# "ValueError: A non-empty list of tiles should be provided to merge." Cartopy OSM

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm currently using OSM in cartopy, python 3.7.

```
t=OSM()
ax.add_image(t, 10)
```

OSM (open street maps) is set to the image at a zoom of 10. But somehow, I get this error
`ValueError: A non-empty list of tiles should be provided to merge.`:
What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and have managed to get to some resolution.

Following suggestions on https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1341

You need to make some changes in the img_tiles.py script which can be found in your python library

/python3.x/site-packages/cartopy/io/

**The changes to be made are:**

add line

`from urllib.request import Request`

within the class GoogleWTS, method get_image (approx line 158)

remove line

`fh = urlopen(url)`

and replace with lines

```
req = Request(url)
req.add_header('User-agent', 'your bot 0.1')
fh = urlopen(req)
```

I understand you are using OSM not GoogleWTS, as am I, so I didn't think this would work but it did.

I can't see all of your code but also make sure that you have this middle line too:

```
t=OSM()
ax = plt.axes(projection=t.crs)
ax.add_image(t, 10)
```

assuming you are trying to use this with Matplotlib